# NSOperation not executing when reorder the Queue

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I'm struggling to get the things right for `NSOperationQueue`.
I have two `tableView` in a `viewController`, one `tableView` Showing full images and other `tableView` shows a kind of gallery view.
In a `webView` I'm loading file and page by page I'm rendering `Images` out of it..and the rending of each Image I'm trying to do in a `NSOperation` Object and this `Operation` object I'm adding to a `NSOperationQueue`.

```
- (void)convertPageToImage
{
    ImageDetails *imageDetails = [[ImageDetails alloc] init];
    // setting some Other required values to imageDetails    
    [self startImageConvertionForCurrentPageWithDetails:imageDetails];
}

- (void)startImageConvertionForCurrentPageWithDetails:(ImageDetails *)imageDetails
{
    if (self.pendingOperations.conversionInProgress)
    {
        // Start downloading
        ImageConverter *imageConverter = [[ImageConverter alloc] initWithImageDetails:imageDetails delegate:self];
        imageConverter.delegate = self;
        [self.pendingOperations.conversionInProgress addObject:imageConverter];
        [self.pendingOperations.conversionQueue addOperation:imageConverter];
        imageDetails = nil;
        imageConverter = nil;
    }
}
```

So far, every thing going good but when I select a thumbnail Image from gallery `TableView` to see it, in full view (i.e. again a `UITableView`) and if that Image is not yet rendered, I want that Image to render first..so I'm create new `NSOperation` with `ImageDetails` Object and reorder `NSOperationQueue` by adding selected Image `Operation` first and than others.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(self.currentSlide <= indexPath.row)
     {
         ImageDetails *imgDetails = [self convertSlideToImage1];
         imgDetails.currentPage = indexPath.row;
         imgDetails.showingPage = indexPath.row;
         [self performSelector:@selector(reorderOperationQueue:) withObject:imgDetails afterDelay:0.0f];
     }
}
```

this is how I reordering `Queue`

```
- (void)reorderOperationQueue :(ImageDetails *) imageDetails
{
    [self.webView stopLoading];
    [self.slideLoaderWebView stopLoading];
    [self.pendingOperations.conversionQueue setSuspended:YES];
    self.pendingOperations.conversionQueue = nil;
    ImageConverter *imageConverter = [[ImageConverter alloc] initWithImageDetails:imageDetails delegate:self];
    [self.pendingOperations.conversionQueue addOperation:imageConverter];
    for(ImageConverter *imgConverter in self.pendingOperations.conversionInProgress)
    {
        if(![imgConverter isEqual:imageConverter])
        {
            if(![imgConverter isFinished])
            [self.pendingOperations.conversionQueue addOperation:imgConverter];
        }
    }
    [self.webView reload];
    [self.slideLoaderWebView reload];
    [self.pendingOperations.conversionInProgress addObject:imageConverter];
    imageConverter = nil;
}
```

Selected Image Converts successfully and display in full view but in this process Sequentially the Images should have been processed/converted, is not getting processed/converted. 
confuse??? let me try by an example. say by this time application have converted 5 images (out of 19) and I am in gallery view and selected 16th Image than I'm creating `NSOperation` to 16th Image and reordering `NSOpreationQueue` such a way that 16th image operation would be first and after that adding rest of all (**NSOpreationQueue should be like 16th img, 6th img, 7th and so on**). So in result 16th images loaded but 6th image is not all loading.
Please give me some clue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your `ImageConverter` class looks like, I guess it is a subclass of `NSOperation`

```
[self.pendingOperations.conversionQueue setSuspended:YES];
```

This call seems to update the individual `NSOperation`s internal flags to reflect the cancelled state. Normally these flags are reset when you resume the Queue, however you never resume the queue you just add the operations again (probably in a cancelled state)

You could try two different things.

1. Try to call resume on the queue using `setSuspended:NO` after you add them again on the queue. (I haven't tried it)
2. You could have two operation queues instead of one (let's call them the normal and the emergency queues), and get rid of the `conversionInProgress` objects (I presume it's an array??), and when you need to convert an image you suspend the normal queue and execute the emergency queue with the selected image... and once processed you resume the normal queue.

Comment: you're right ImageConverter is a subclass of NSOperation, and it simply has main method implementation and some image rendering methods implementation.
As far as your 1st suggestion is concern, I'm not all using old queue. assigning nil to old queue and creating a new queue.So I guess no need to setting Suspended to YES. I really like your 2nd point and I'm going to go that way. let you know after tying. well thanks for a quick reply.

Comment: @SuryakantSharma I know you're not using old queue, but you're reusing the operations, even if you assign nil, the operations are kept intact in `conversionInProgress` with a suspended state. So when you add them to the queue again they might still be suspended.

Comment: suspended state are for Queue not for Operation.

Comment: @SuryakantSharma I'm sorry you're right. I was thinking about `cancelled` operations while writing about `suspended` operations. I guess it's too late here and I need some sleep.

Comment: thanks for your replies. I'll try your 2nd suggestion and  let you know...have a good sleep.

Comment: hey, the problem wasn't in NSOperation and NSOperationQueue. it was in other part of the code but your answer according to the info I've shared in the question, is really valuable, so upvoting it. thanks